# Can not get values in database using angular.js and php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i am unable to fill database after post by the user using angular.js and PHP.After clicking on submit button the row is created inside MySQL database but no values is there.Please cehck my code below.

> add_data.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Add_Data">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CRUD APPLICATION</title>
<script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/create.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
#dv1{
     border:1px solid #DBDCE9; margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;width:220px;
     border-radius:7px;padding: 25px;
}
.info{
     border: 1px solid;margin: 10px 0px;
     padding:10px;color: #00529B;
     background-color: #BDE5F8;list-style: none;
}
.err{
   border: 1px solid;  margin: 10px 0px;
   padding:10px;  color: #D8000C;
   background-color: #FFBABA;   list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='dv1'>
  <form ng-controller="FrmController">
                <ul>
                    <li class="err" ng-repeat="error in errors"> {{ error}} </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="info" ng-repeat="msg in msgs"> {{ msg}} </li>
                </ul>
                <h2>Sigup Form</h2>
                <div>
                    <label>Name</label> 
                    <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="User Name" style='margin-left: 22px;'> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="useremail" placeholder="Email" style='margin-left: 22px;'> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="userpassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button ng-click='SignUp();' style='margin-left: 63px;margin-top:10px'>SignUp</button>
     </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> create.js:

```
var app=angular.module('Add_Data',[]);
app.controller('FrmController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];
    $scope.SignUp=function(){
        $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
        $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);

        $http.post('php/create.php', {'uname': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword, 'email': $scope.useremail}
               ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.msg != '')
                    {
                        $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                    }
                    else
                      {
                         $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                      }
                    }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
                        $scope.errors.push(status);
         });
    }
});
```

> create.php:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname);
$upswd = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pswd);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '******');
mysql_select_db('AngularTest', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where email ="' . $uemail . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

if ($res['cnt'] == 0) {
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO users (name,pass,email) values ("' . $usrname . '","' . $upswd . '","' . $uemail . '")';
    $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
    if ($qry_res) {
        $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    } else {
        $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record');
        $jsn = json_encode($arr);
        print_r($jsn);
    }
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}

?>
```

When user is clicking of signup button one row is created inside the database but the three field is showing blank.I am also getting the message `user created successfully` on the page.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: That means you are not getting the corresponding varibles($usrname, $upswd & $uemail) in the PHP side, Check why is that.

Comment: it's the quote action i believe. echo out the vars, too

Comment: @MaK : so here how can i get those values ?

Comment: Are you sure that data you are getting in `file_get_contents("php://input");` is in json format? It might be possible that you are getting formdata. check your request headers once.